# Get Content of a page on another domain

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, cross-domain

We want to get the html content of a page on another domain. The following considerations are present:
1- The login page has a I am not a robot recaptcha.
2- The load of page in iFrame is restricted.
3- Could not use jQuery get or load methods because of cross domain restrictions.

With these limitations is it possible to develop a crawler or even use some client side codes to get data?
Thanks

Comment: _Could not use jQuery get or load methods because of cross domain restrictions.._ That restrictions are not only specific to jQuery, but applied to _all_ client code.

Comment: @hindmost ok. Just want to say the restrictions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually.. **NO**

But you can take the help of a backend server.
Let the server download the page and send it to the client.

This would solve problems related to CORS restrictions.

Coming to the captcha part, if the page operations are restricted by the captcha, then again there aren't much you can do. If it was that easy, the captcha wouldn't be used in the first place.

Comment: Purely using a web client - No. With the help of a server - Yes

Comment: Even with a captcha? then, how?

Comment: Depends on the page and what you want to do with it. If you want to perform login on that page (provided you can't login without the captcha), You CAN'T. If you just want the page content, you might get it

Comment: The login page needs captcha.

Comment: And you want to Login using the 'bot'?

Comment: Yes I want to login with bot

Comment: Then tough luck. Only get around is if you find a way to solve the captcha. If it is provided by google, then its straight game over.